# How does Ray manage to grab Conny's bunny plushy and hide it from her?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

Re-watching The Promised Neverland anime and re-reading the manga, I still find the first major plot turning event a bit abrupt. Conny is saying goodbye to her friends at the house foyer with Mom behind her, holding her beloved bunny toy. And the next scene is Mom leading her to the gate without the bunny. The assumption is they go out the door straight after waving goodbye. So how did Ray pull it off?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error introduced in the anime. In the manga, Conny is not shown to be holding Little Bunny when she leaves, as seen in the first chapter.

[image: Close up of panel]

[image: Conny misplaces Little Bunny]

Later on, it is shown in chapter 13 how Ray gets Little Bunny.

[image: Ray and Norman talking about Little Bunny]
[image]

This is just my interpretation since there's no dialogue, but it looks like Ray non-verbally offers to hold Little Bunny while he's handing over the suitcase. Since Ray is being so sneaky, Conny just forgets she's no longer holding her toy after the exchange. It's also possible he just asked for it. But given how attached Conny was to the toy, it seems unlikely she would have meant to permanently hand it over into Ray's custody.

**Anime Continuity**

Since Conny is explicitly shown to have the toy as she's leaving Gracefield, events couldn't have happened as they did in the manga. But since there is likely no actual explanation given in the show, we can only speculate on possibilities.

First off, there's the possibility that Ray somehow acquired a second Little Bunny. I don't think he could sew one himself though (notwithstanding whether Ray can sew, this would require materials, tools, and the time and space to make the duplicate in secret).

I think the more likely possibility hinges on toys being recycled and Ray being Isabella's spy. We know toys are recycled and stored in the secret room, because we see this during the series (see [Little Bunny](https://yakusokunoneverland.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Bunny_(Anime)) and [Grace Field](https://yakusokunoneverland.fandom.com/wiki/Grace_Field_House_secret_room) secret room).

Conny would obviously have no further need for the toy where she's going, so it could be that it was Isabella who took it from Conny. She may have even persuaded Conny to give it up before they left. From here, there are two options:

1. Ray may have then taken it from where Isabella stashed it and placed it where Emma and Norman find it.
2. Being Isabella's spy, Isabella may have directly given Ray the toy and instructed him to stash it somewhere. He instead places it where Emma and Norman find it.